# Data Lake Store .Net SDK crash after multiple operations send from the same ip (host)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-data-lake

currently I disovered some problems with data lake store .net sdk which i use in my asp.net mvc 5 application. When I perform multiple action to my data lake store (like send some new data to store) I always receive error : 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.44.88.112:443 .

I don't know why it's happen? I need to change some value in data lake store that allow me to send many items in the same time to my store (to different files) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to write to multiple files at once with multiple threads.  This should be supported.
Can you tell us which SDK and which version you are using?  Can you paste sample code which is failing?